# How to make a drag and drop page builder from scratch

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

My goal is to make a tool to add html elements on a blank page to make a web page.
I know it could be done with jquery's drag and drop but the problem is I don't have any idea how to organize the elements when you drag another one below it.

Like for real I don't have the slightest idea on meeting my goal. Any suggestions would help me alot.

Comment: The scope of your question is far too broad, and is likely to be closed. Try to ask specific questions, and provide sufficient detail about what you're trying to achieve, and what you have tried thus far when doing so.

Comment: So you wish to build an HTML editor (like if there wasn't already plenty) using a technology you don't master at all... Good luck.

Comment: I know how to ride a bicycle .... now how do I build a Rocket??

Comment: Sorry guys if the question is composed badly. But thanks for the comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ive worked on multiple drag and drop builders in the past. And it can get pretty rough down the road.

I wouldnt recommend you start building one from scratch, instead take an already opensourced project and try to modify it to make it your own.

A good opensourced project on the market right now is this one:
https://github.com/artf/grapesjs

It is built on BackboneJS, so a little reading may be required.

If you have any questions feel free to send me a dm.

Good luck bro.

Comment: Thanks bro. I'll try this when I get home

Comment: Sure thing bro. Keep me posted.

Comment: where can I dm you? I can't dm you on twitter

Comment: https://twitter.com/richaardabear should be good.

Comment: still can't dm you on twitter. maybe you disabled direct messages to others who are not following you? I'll just follow you. have some questions to ask

Comment: hey richard, I do have some questions. but I couldn't dm you in twitter any other way to contact you? how about email?

Comment: Another open source drag and drop builder is https://github.com/givanz/VvvebJs

Comment: Another flow builder : https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow